# how to edit an html file inside chm file in python

Tags: chm

I am working on a chm project. Is there a way to open and edit with Python (or other way but I prefer Python) the HTML compiled in the chm files so it can be updated without recompile?

I have tried the chm and chmlib in Python with no luck. I am trying to find a way to edit existed chm file. Any suggestions?

Comment: What kind of error you encountered ?

Comment: no error, for future modifications...

Answer (score 3):

No solution but to decompile the CHM, make the modifications and recompile.

Depending on the complexity of the CHM file, it might be better to reuse the original sources, not the compiled CHM, since a decompilation-recompilation step with free tools won't always recreate the same CHM.

There are various decompilers, but only two freely available compilers, one by Microsoft, and one by the Free Pascal Team. (use for e.g. Preshrunk Cotton python project and in some distributions.)

You could also investigate some commercial tools. They probably do a better job than the open source decompilers.